# How to disallow temporaries

Tags: c++

For a class Foo, is there a way to disallow constructing it without giving it a name?

For example:

```
Foo("hi");
```

And only allow it if you give it a name, like the following?

```
Foo my_foo("hi");
```

The lifetime of the first one is just the statement, and the second one is the enclosing block.  In my use case, `Foo` is measuring the time between constructor and destructor. Since I never refer to the local variable, I often forget to put it in, and accidentally change the lifetime.  I'd like to get a compile time error instead.

Comment: This could also come in handy for mutex lock guards.

Comment: Well, you _could_ write your own C++ compiler where it was forbidden, but strictly speaking it wouldn't be C++ then. There are also places where temporaries like that would be useful, like when returning an object from a function for example (like `return std::string("Foo");`)

Comment: Nope, you can't do this, sorry

Comment: Depending on your religion this might be a case where macros could come handy (by usnig that type only ever via a macro that always creates a varaible)

Comment: Constructors aren't real member functions. They don't operate on an existing object, and thus there's no way of knowing whether the purported object is a temporary or not. There is no *ref-qualifier* for constructors.

Comment: Seems more like something I'd want my LINT tool to catch than something I'd want to syntactically prevent by a compiler hack.

Comment: +1 for telling [WHY](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4ZoJKF_VuA)

Comment: @KerrekSB: if ref-qualifiers were allowed on destructors then that would work. Unfortunately they aren't.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Another macro-based solution:

```
#define Foo class Foo
```

The statement `Foo("hi");` expands to `class Foo("hi");`, which is ill-formed; but `Foo a("hi")` expands to `class Foo a("hi")`, which is correct.

This has the advantage that it is both source- and binary-compatible with existing (correct) code. **(This claim is not entirely correct - please see Johannes Schaub's Comment and ensuing discussion below:  *"How can you know that it is source compatible with existing code? His friend includes his header and has void f() { int Foo = 0; } which previously compiled fine and now miscompiles! Also, every line that defines a member function of class Foo fails: void class Foo::bar() {}"*)**

Comment: I think this is what we'll go with, although it doesn't work if Foo is in a namespace:  A user who writes 'Stats::Foo a("hi");' will be in for a surprise.  The other solution is a macro like FOO(a, "hi"), which is ugly, is a non-standard way to declare a local variable, etc.

Comment: How can you know that it is source compatible with existing code? His friend includes his header and has `void f() { int Foo = 0; }` which previously compiled fine and now miscompiles! Also, every line that defines a member function of class Foo fails: `void class Foo::bar() {}`.

Comment: How can this get so many votes? Just look at the comment by @JohannesSchaub-litb and you will understand that this is a really bad solution. Because all of the definitions of member functions are invalid after this.. -1 from my side

Comment: @Aamir one can simply undefine the macro inside foo.cpp. No problem.

Comment: @JustMaximumPower: I hope that was sarcastic because if not, it is again a bad (read worse) workaround. Because we are back to square one after undefining it, which means that you will not get a compilation error (which the OP intended) on a similar line i.e., `Foo("Hi")` inside Foo.cpp now

Comment: @Aamir No I'm serious. Martin C. Martin intents to use it to guard the usage of Foo not the implementation.

Comment: I think .. forward declarations shall not in this solution. Do let me know if it works in that scenario.

Comment: I tried in Visual Studio 2012 and found `class Foo("hi");` is OK for compiling.

Comment: -1 for use of macros, and I would give another -1 for breaking other code

Answer (score 71):

How about a little hack

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo (const char*) {}
};

void Foo (float);


int main ()
{
    Foo ("hello"); // error
    class Foo a("hi"); // OK
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Great Hack! One note: `Foo a("hi");` (without `class`) would be an error, too.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Foo("hello") tries to call void Foo(float) and it results in a linker error ? But why is the float version called instead of the Foo ctor ?

Comment: undu, hm what compiler are you using? gcc 3.4 complains that there is no conversion to float. It tries to call a function `Foo` because it takes a precedence over a class.

Comment: @aleguna actually I didn't try to run this code, that was just a (bad) guess :s But you answered my question anyway, I didn't know function takes precedence over class.

Comment: @didierc no, `Foo::Foo("hi")` is disallowed in C++.

Comment: @MatthieuM. +1 for making my day.

Comment: @didierc i suppose that gcc0.1 is not compliant either.

Comment: @didierc why are you telling me this? please tell this to the gcc maintainers. and i suspect that they dont care to fix past gcc versions either.

Comment: @didierc it's no ones call to notify developers that an old version of their software does things wrong. gcc does it correct in its recent versions.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I'll take your word for it :)

Answer (score 42):

Make the constructor private but give the class a *create* method.

Comment: -1: How does this solve the OP's problem at all? You can still write `Foo::create();` over `Foo const & x = Foo::create();`

Comment: @ThomasEding I guess you are right, it doesn't fix OP's core problem, but just forces him think and not make the mistake he is making.

Comment: @ThomasEding you cannot protect yourself against angry users that want to break the system. Even with @ecatmur's hack you can say `std::common_type<Foo>::type()` and you get a temporary. Or even `typedef Foo bar; bar()`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: But the big difference is whether or not it was by mistake or not. There's almost no way typing `std::common_type<Foo>::type()` is by mistake. Leaving out the `Foo const & x = ...` by accident is totally believable.

Answer (score 25):

This one doesn't result in a compiler error, but a runtime error. Instead of measuring a wrong time, you get an exception which may be acceptable too.

Any constructor you want to guard needs a default argument on which `set(guard)` is called.

```
struct Guard {
  Guard()
    :guardflagp()
  { }

  ~Guard() {
    assert(guardflagp && "Forgot to call guard?");
    *guardflagp = 0;
  }

  void *set(Guard const *&guardflag) {
    if(guardflagp) {
      *guardflagp = 0;
    }

    guardflagp = &guardflag;
    *guardflagp = this;
  }

private:
  Guard const **guardflagp;
};

class Foo {
public:
  Foo(const char *arg1, Guard &&g = Guard()) 
    :guard()
  { g.set(guard); }

  ~Foo() {
    assert(!guard && "A Foo object cannot be temporary!");
  }

private:
  mutable Guard const *guard;
};
```

The characteristics are:

```
Foo f() {
  // OK (no temporary)
  Foo f1("hello");

  // may throw (may introduce a temporary on behalf of the compiler)
  Foo f2 = "hello";

  // may throw (introduces a temporary that may be optimized away
  Foo f3 = Foo("hello");

  // OK (no temporary)
  Foo f4{"hello"};

  // OK (no temporary)
  Foo f = { "hello" };

  // always throws
  Foo("hello");

  // OK (normal copy)
  return f;

  // may throw (may introduce a temporary on behalf of the compiler)
  return "hello";

  // OK (initialized temporary lives longer than its initializers)
  return { "hello" };
}

int main() {
  // OK (it's f that created the temporary in its body)
  f();

  // OK (normal copy)
  Foo g1(f());

  // OK (normal copy)
  Foo g2 = f();
}
```

The case of `f2`, `f3` and the return of `"hello"` may not be wanted. To prevent throwing, you can allow the source of a copy to be a temporary, by resetting the `guard` to now guard us instead of the source of the copy. Now you also see why we used the pointers above - it allows us to be flexible.

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo(const char *arg1, Guard &&g = Guard()) 
    :guard()
  { g.set(guard); }

  Foo(Foo &&other)
    :guard(other.guard)
  {
    if(guard) {
      guard->set(guard);
    }
  }

  Foo(const Foo& other)
    :guard(other.guard)
  {
    if(guard) {
      guard->set(guard);
    }
  }

  ~Foo() {
    assert(!guard && "A Foo object cannot be temporary!");
  }

private:
  mutable Guard const *guard;
};
```

The characteristics for `f2`, `f3` and for `return "hello"` are now always `// OK`.

Comment: `Foo f = "hello"; // may throw` This is enough to scare me into never using this code.

Comment: @thomas, i recommend to mark the constructor `explicit` and then such code no more compiles. the goal was to fotbid the temporary, and it does. if you are scared, you can make it not throw by setting the source of a copy in the copy or move constructor to be a nontemporary. then only the final object of several copies may throw if it still ends up as a temporary.

Comment: @ThomasEding i implemented that tweak now.

Comment: My god. I'm not novice in C++ and C++11, but I can't understand how does this work. Could you please add a couple of explanations?..

Comment: @Mikhail the order of destruction of temporary objects that are destroyed at the same points is the reverse order of their construction. The default argument that the caller passes is a temporary. If the `Foo` object is a temporary too, and its lifetime ends in the same expression as the default argument, then the `Foo` object's dtor will be invoked before the default argument's dtor, because the former was created after the latter.

Comment: If for some reason the lifetime of the temporary is extended or the object is not a temporary and thus lives longer (the former also happens in `const Foo& f = Foo("hello");`), it's the inverse.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Very nice trick. I really thought it is impossible to distinguish `Foo(...);` and `Foo foo(...);` from inside the `Foo`.

Answer (score 19):

A few years ago I wrote [a patch](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=15798&action=diff) for the GNU C++ compiler which adds a new warning option for that situation. This is tracked in [a Bugzilla item](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36587).

Unfortunately, GCC Bugzilla is a burial ground where well-considered patch-included feature suggestions go to die. :)

This was motivated by the desire to catch exactly the sort of bugs that are the subject of this question in code which uses local objects as gadgets for locking and unlocking, measuring execution time and so forth.

Answer (score 9):

As is, with your implementation, you cannot do this, but you can use this rule to your advantage:

> Temporary objects cannot be bound to non-const references

You can move the code from the class to an freestanding function which takes a non-const reference parameter. If you do so, You will get a compiler error if an temporary tries to bind to the non-const reference.

#### [Code Sample](http://ideone.com/uEp4Zk)

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo(const char* ){}
        friend void InitMethod(Foo& obj);
};

void InitMethod(Foo& obj){}

int main()
{
    Foo myVar("InitMe");
    InitMethod(myVar);    //Works

    InitMethod("InitMe"); //Does not work  
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:13: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Foo&’ from a temporary of type ‘const char*’
prog.cpp:7: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void InitMethod(Foo&)’
```

Comment: @didierc: Provided they provide a additional function.It's up to you to not do so.We are trying to tweak a way to achieve something not explicitly allowed by the standard, so ofcourse there will be restrictions.

Comment: @didierc the parameter `x` is a named object so it is not clear whether we really want to forbid it. If the constructor you would have used is explicit, may people would instinctively do `Foo f = Foo("hello");`. I think they would become angry if it failed. My solution initially rejected it (and very similar cases) with an exception/assert-failure and someone complained.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Yes, OP wants to  forbid discarding the value generated by a constructor by forcing bindings. My example is wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Simply don't have a default constructor, and do require a reference to an instance in every constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum SelfRef { selfRef };

struct S
{
    S( SelfRef, S const & ) {}
};

int main()
{
    S a( selfRef, a );
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but as soon as you have one variable: `S(selfRef, a);`. :/

Comment: @Xeo `S(SelfRef, S const& s) { assert(&s == this); }`, if a runtime error is acceptable.

Answer (score 6):

No, I'm afraid this isn't possible. But you could get the same effect by creating a macro.

```
#define FOO(x) Foo _foo(x)
```

With this in place, you can just write FOO(x) instead of Foo my_foo(x).

Comment: I was going to upvote, but then I saw "you could create a macro".

Comment: @lucasclemente, s/forbidden/reserved/

Comment: Ok, fixed the underscores.
@Griwes - Don't be a fundamentalist. It is better to say "use a macro" than "this can't be done".

Comment: Well, it can't be done. You haven't solved the problem at all, it's still perfectly legal to do `Foo();`.

Comment: Now you are being stubborn here. Rename the Foo class something complicated, and call the macro Foo. Problem solved.

Comment: Something like: `class Do_not_use_this_class_directly_Only_use_it_via_the_FOO_macro;`

Comment: You don't even need to change the class's name. Just define the macro after the class with the exact same name as the class and undefine the macro in the implementation file. Though, I think adding a macro param for the var name would be nice. That way, you can access the variable.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley When compilation errors *do* occur, it will look really weird...

Answer (score 4):

Since the primary goal is to prevent bugs, consider this:

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo( const char* ) { /* ... */ }
};

enum { Foo };

int main()
{
  struct Foo foo( "hi" ); // OK
  struct Foo( "hi" ); // fail
  Foo foo( "hi" ); // fail
  Foo( "hi" ); // fail
}
```

That way you can't forget to name the variable and you can't forget to write `struct`. Verbose, but safe.

Answer (score 1):

Declare one-parametric constructor as explicit and nobody will ever create an object of that class unintentionally.

For example

```
class Foo
{
public: 
  explicit Foo(const char*);
};

void fun(const Foo&);
```

can only be used this way

```
void g() {
  Foo a("text");
  fun(a);
}
```

but never this way (through a temporary on the stack)

```
void g() {
  fun("text");
}
```

See also: Alexandrescu, C++ Coding Standards, Item 40.

Comment: This does allow `fun(Foo("text"));`.